# ansible read (more than one) values from a line in file

Tags: ansible, lookup

i am trying to read variables from a file into an array of something, but not into a pre defined variable.

The goal is a playbook, that searches for lines with item.0 and NOT item.1 and deletes them, later the playbook makes sure, that a line with item.0 item.1 is present, thats why i need this splitted.

For example i have a file with lines like this:

```
Parameter Value
Parameter Value
Parameter Value
```

to use this in a loop until EOF.

example part ot the playbook:

```
- name: lineinfile loop
  lineinfile:
    path: /myfile
    regexp '^{{somethinglike item.0}}.(?!{{something like item.1}})'
    state absent
    ...
```

Does anybody know a solution for the lookup and the loop?

Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solutuion:

There is a ansible role in ansible galaxy, it provides exactly what i need:

https://github.com/mkouhei/ansible-role-includecsv

Answer (score 0):

This should help you.

Input file

```
cat filein 
Parameter1,Value1
Parameter2,Value2
Parameter3,Value3
```

Playbook:

```
---
- hosts: test

  tasks:


  - name: reg
    shell: cat filein
    register: myitems


  - name: deb
    debug: var=myitems.stdout_lines


  - name: echo to file
    shell: "echo {{ item.split(',')[1] }} - {{ item.split(',')[0] }}  >> fileout"
    with_items: "{{ myitems.stdout_lines }}"
```

Output file:

```
cat fileout 
Value1 - Parameter1
Value2 - Parameter2
Value3 - Parameter3
```

This is not state of the art but should work.

Comment: Thank you, but shell searches for the file on the destination-host, i need that file where the playbook is

Comment: ansible-playbook -i hosts -c local playbook.yml